# How to overlay a transparent PNG over video and scale to video size in FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay

Right now I overlay a transparent PNG over a video first converting them both to the same size, but would love to just have it scale within the same command. Here’s the command now:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex 'overlay[out],amix=inputs=1,pan=stereo:c0=c0:c1=c1' -map '[out]' output.mp4
```

The best command should also permit a video that does not have an audio track and still overlay the PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i overlay.png
 -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v]"
 -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -ac 2 output.mp4
```

The `scale2ref` scales the first input (to the filter) to the size of the second. The input pad indexes `0`, and `1` refer to the first and 2nd input to FFmpeg, as that count begins from zero.

`-map 0:a?` - the `?` tells FFmpeg to map the audio contingently i.e. if present. I have removed the `amix` since a) filters within a filter complex can't be contingent and b) there's only one input so there's nothing to 'mix'.

Comment: This is great - if I want to scale the second input to the size of the first, would it be `[0][1]scale2ref[i][m]`?

Comment: Thanks for solution. Is it possible to change overlay.png while video is streaming? Means changing image ovelay dynamically. Is it possible?

Comment: Using stream loop on input and input should be a soft link to actual image. Point link to new file when you want to change it.

Comment: @DanielJacobArcher as far as I understand it, the right part of a filter is always names you provide yourself. So switching i and m will only influence following filters, not the scale2ref filter itself. You'd need to switch the left-side names as well: `[1][0]scale2ref[m][i]`

Comment: I meant to write `[0][1]scale2ref[m][i]`, obviously, as the first (index 0) `-i` is the video, hence the REF.